# Why is my SHA1 hash not matching?

Tags: php, sha1

I don't think I was specific enough last time. Here we go:

I have a hex string:

> 742713478fb3c36e014d004100440041004
> e0041004e00000060f347d15798c9010060
> 6b899c5a98c9014d007900470072006f007
> 500700000002f0000001f7691944b9a3306
> 295fb5f1f57ca52090d35b50060606060606

The last 20 bytes should (theoretically) contain a SHA1 Hash of the first part (complete string - 20 bytes). But it doesn't match for me.

Trying to do this with PHP, but no luck. Can you get a match?

#### Ticket:

> 742713478fb3c36e014d004100
> 440041004e0041004e00000060
> f347d15798c90100606b899c5a
> 98c9014d007900470072006f00
> 7500700000002f0000001f7691944b9a

#### sha1 hash of ticket appended to original:

> 3306295fb5f1f57ca52090d35b50060606060606

#### My sha1 hash of ticket:

> b6ecd613698ac3533b5f853bf22f6eb4afb94239

Here's what is in the ticket and how it's being stored. FWIW, I can pull out username, etc, and spot the various delimiters.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Forms_Auth_Internals/AuthTicket2.JPG

Edited: I have discovered that the string is padded on the end by the decryption function it goes through before this point. I removed the last 6 bytes and adjusted by ticket and hash accordingly. Still doesn't work, but I'm closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ticket is being calculated on the hex string itself. Maybe the appended hash is calculated on another representation of the same data?

Comment: To clarify, I tried trimming the last 20 bytes from the raw data, no luck.

Comment: What format do you get the value in? What is the value itself representing? Where are you getting it? Hashes are chaotic by design: different formats will make a huge difference. Can you not ask how the original hash is being calculated?

Comment: The ticket: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Forms_Auth_Internals/AuthTicket2.JPG  This is hashed, the hash is then appended.

Comment: Yeah, but what is being hashed? Is it being hashed byte by byte? Is its hex, octal, decimal, etc representation being hashed? Is this something you can find out?

Comment: So you accepted my answer? What was the actual problem? I'm curious.

Comment: It's a hunch. I'm still working on it, but this must be the problem as my .net cohort can replicate the hash on his end. I'll update with what I discover when I finish.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, but it's narrowed down to something to do with the way I'm representing my hex data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615157/how-do-i-sha1-hash-hex-values-correctly-in-php

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting confused about bytes vs characters.

Internally, php stores every character in a string as a byte. The sha1 hash that PHP generates is a 40 character (40 byte) hexademical representation of the 20-byte binary data, since each binary value needs to be represented by 2 hex characters.

I'm not sure if this is the actual source of your discrepancy, but seeing this misunderstanding makes me wonder if it's related.

Comment: $ticket = substr($decrypthex, 0, -40);
$hash = substr($decrypthex, -40);
echo sha1($ticket);

Comment: Still characters... What you want to do is for each 2 characters, do chr(hexdec('0b')); (0b is an example, ill let you create the loop logic)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if the original code is in ASP.net, you may also have a character encoding difference (UTF-8 vs ASCII)

Answer (score 2):

Try trimming the string first, its suprisingly easy to have a newline or space on the end that changes the hash completely.

Comment: I can correctly extract other information and on examination of the string it is formatted appropriately, delimiters where expected, etc. I wish this was the problem!

Comment: Actually, that is indeed part of the problem. The string is decrypted, and the function used pads the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Online SHA1 tool](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/) the hash of the given text (after removing new lines and spaces) is

```
b6ecd613698ac3533b5f853bf22f6eb4afb94239
```

Idea: Make sure your inputing characters not a hex number to the PHP version.

Comment: That's what I'm getting, see above where I show My sha1 hash of ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the original was a keyed hash. I had to use hash_hmac() with a validation key rather than sha1() without.