# How do I sha1 hash hex values correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, hex

I have a series of hex bytes. Theoretically, the last 20 bytes are the sha1 hash of the first part:

```
3F F4 E5 25 98 20 52 70 01 63 00 68 00 75 00 79 00 69 00 00 00 74 28 96 10 09 9D C9 01 00 74 A0 D7 DB 0B 9D C9 01 4D 00 79 00 47 00 72 00 6F 00 75 00 70 00 00 00 2F 00 00 00 BD 0D EA 71 BE 0B 25 75 E7 5C 58 20 31 57 F3 9A EF 69 1B FD
```

If I apply sha1 to them in PHP like this:

```
echo sha1("3FF4E525982052700163006800750079006900000074289610099DC9010074A0D7DB0B9DC9014D007900470072006F007500700000002F000000");
```

I get back:

```
d68ca0839df6e5ac7069cc548d82f249752f3acb
```

But I'm looking for this value:

```
bd0dea71be0b2575e75c58203157f39aef691bfd  

(BD 0D EA 71 BE 0B 25 75 E7 5C 58 20 31 57 F3 9A EF 69 1B FD)
```

Is it because I'm treating the hex values as a string? What do I need to do?

Edit:

Here's the original information I am working from:

```
ticketBytes
{byte[0x0000003a]}
    [0x00000000]: 0x3f
    [0x00000001]: 0xf4
    [0x00000002]: 0xe5
    [0x00000003]: 0x25
    [0x00000004]: 0x98
    [0x00000005]: 0x20
    [0x00000006]: 0x52
    [0x00000007]: 0x70
    [0x00000008]: 0x01
    [0x00000009]: 0x63
    [0x0000000a]: 0x00
    [0x0000000b]: 0x68
    [0x0000000c]: 0x00
    [0x0000000d]: 0x75
    [0x0000000e]: 0x00
    [0x0000000f]: 0x79
    [0x00000010]: 0x00
    [0x00000011]: 0x69
    [0x00000012]: 0x00
    [0x00000013]: 0x00
    [0x00000014]: 0x00
    [0x00000015]: 0x74
    [0x00000016]: 0x28
    [0x00000017]: 0x96
    [0x00000018]: 0x10
    [0x00000019]: 0x09
    [0x0000001a]: 0x9d
    [0x0000001b]: 0xc9
    [0x0000001c]: 0x01
    [0x0000001d]: 0x00
    [0x0000001e]: 0x74
    [0x0000001f]: 0xa0
    [0x00000020]: 0xd7
    [0x00000021]: 0xdb
    [0x00000022]: 0x0b
    [0x00000023]: 0x9d
    [0x00000024]: 0xc9
    [0x00000025]: 0x01
    [0x00000026]: 0x4d
    [0x00000027]: 0x00
    [0x00000028]: 0x79
    [0x00000029]: 0x00
    [0x0000002a]: 0x47
    [0x0000002b]: 0x00
    [0x0000002c]: 0x72
    [0x0000002d]: 0x00
    [0x0000002e]: 0x6f
    [0x0000002f]: 0x00
    [0x00000030]: 0x75
    [0x00000031]: 0x00
    [0x00000032]: 0x70
    [0x00000033]: 0x00
    [0x00000034]: 0x00
    [0x00000035]: 0x00
    [0x00000036]: 0x2f
    [0x00000037]: 0x00
    [0x00000038]: 0x00
    [0x00000039]: 0x00

hashed
{byte[0x00000014]}
    [0x00000000]: 0xbd
    [0x00000001]: 0x0d
    [0x00000002]: 0xea
    [0x00000003]: 0x71
    [0x00000004]: 0xbe
    [0x00000005]: 0x0b
    [0x00000006]: 0x25
    [0x00000007]: 0x75
    [0x00000008]: 0xe7
    [0x00000009]: 0x5c
    [0x0000000a]: 0x58
    [0x0000000b]: 0x20
    [0x0000000c]: 0x31
    [0x0000000d]: 0x57
    [0x0000000e]: 0xf3
    [0x0000000f]: 0x9a
    [0x00000010]: 0xef
    [0x00000011]: 0x69
    [0x00000012]: 0x1b
    [0x00000013]: 0xfd
```

Comment: Are you sure that the algorithm used is SHA1?

Comment: Confirmed that it's sha1. If it wasn't, it would be shorter than 20 bytes.

Comment: Well if it's SHA1, then not of these 58 bytes.

Comment: I'm going to get my .NET coworker to confirm that he can get the hash out of the data. Thanks, and I'll update when I find out.

Comment: Ah, BTW, to avoid all these tedious conversions, it's better to have these bytes in the format "\x3F\xF4\xE5\x25\x98...."

Comment: Thanks, added hex values from my original problem.

Comment: Still, any way I try it, still yields "fa3ebc158305d09443b4315d35c0eee5aa72daef". Not only in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is very wrong here. [SHA1 digests are 160 bits](http://www.w3.org/PICS/DSig/SHA1_1_0.html), which is 20 hexadecimal numbers, which is represented by 40 characters.  The value you're expecting is 32 characters, which means it's not a SHA1 digest - or something else is missing that I don't yet understand.

Comment: Sorry about the misinformation, edited question with correct "expected" value.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this doesn't give you the correct value either, but it might point you in the right direction. Either way it's a much better idea to actually convert the hex code to a binary string before hashing it. Like this:

```
$str = "3F F4 E5 25 98 20 52 70 01 63 00 68 00 75 00 79 00 69 00 00 00 74 28 96 10 09 9D C9 01 00 74 A0 D7 DB 0B 9D C9 01 4D 00 79 00 47 00 72 00 6F 00 75 00 70 00 00 00 2F 00 00 00";

// Create an array where each entry represents a single byte in hex
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
// Convert the hex to decimal
$arr = array_map("hexdec", $arr);
// Convert the decimal number into the corresponding ASCII character
$arr = array_map("chr", $arr);

// Implode the array into a string, and hash the result
$result = sha1(implode($arr));

echo $result."\n";
```

The result is fa3ebc158305d09443b4315d35c0eee5aa72daef, which is what vartecs code produces as well. I think there's some aspect of how the correct reference is calculated that we don't know, because the approach used here and by vartec is definitely the most logical way to do it based on the facts that we do know.

Answer (score 2):

```
$hexes = "3F F4 E5 25 98 20 52 70 01 63 00 68 00 75 00 79 00 69 00 00 00 74 28 96 10 09 9D C9 01 00 74 A0 D7 DB 0B 9D C9 01 4D 00 79 00 47 00 72 00 6F 00 75 00 70 00 00 00 2F 00 00 00";
$hexes = split(' ',$hexes);
$hexes = array_map('hexdec',$hexes);
$hexes = call_user_func_array('pack',array_merge(array('C*'),$hexes));
echo sha1($hexes);
```

BTW. you can achieve same thing by passing it in another format:

```
$hexes = "\x3F\xF4\xE5\x25\x98\x20\x52\x70\x01\x63\x00\x68\x00\x75\x00\x79\x00\x69\x00\x00\x00\x74\x28\x96\x10\x09\x9D\xC9\x01\x00\x74\xA0\xD7\xDB\x0B\x9D\xC9\x01\x4D\x00\x79\x00\x47\x00\x72\x00\x6F\x00\x75\x00\x70\x00\x00\x00\x2F\x00\x00\x00";
echo sha1($hexes);
```

Answer (score 1):

convert them into string using `chr()`..

```
$string = "3f ........"
$c = split(' ',$string);
$string2 = '';
foreach( $c as $char )
{
 $string2 .= chr(hexdec($c));
}

echo sha1($string2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pack` function](http://docs.php.net/pack) to convert the hexadecimal string into binary:

```
$bin = pack('H*', preg_replace('/[^0-9a-fA-F]+/', '', $hex));
```

Comment: This gives me the same results as emil's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function strToHex($string)
{
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}
echo sha1(strToHex("3FF4E525982052700163006800750079006900000074289610099DC9010074A0D7DB0B9DC9014D007900470072006F007500700000002F000000"));

>> 5b102a482247fef726843f214f8a81b1627bb634
```

Comment: i am not sure here, but wouldn't you want to iterate the string in reverse order from your example code?  something more like: for ($i = strlen($string); $i> 0 ; $i++)

Comment: No... infinite loop. i will always be larger than 0.

Comment: I think this example is the strangest of all the suggestions. dechex(ord()) seems totally unlogical in this case. ord() converts every single hexcharacter into ascii, which is then converted back to hex. what's the point of that, exactly?

Comment: every single hexcharacter into the converting ascii code, that is. just to avoid any missunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I needed to use hash_hmac() with a validation key rather than sha1().