# sha1 function giving a different result to equivalent .net code

Tags: c#, php, .net, sha1

I have the following PHP code:

```
$stringToHash = "10123456789"."2014:11:25-15:42:00"."20.00"."826"."sharedsecret";

echo($stringToHash);
// outputs:
// 101234567892014:11:25-15:42:0020.00826sharedsecret

$ascii = bin2hex($stringToHash);

echo($ascii);
// outputs:   
// 3130313233343536373839323031343a31313a32352d31353a34323a303032302e3030383236736861726564736563726574

$sha = sha1($ascii);

echo($sha);
// outputs:
// 847aa9da32c54ed8bb9183007336f5762a62ef20
```

Here is the equivalent C# code:

```
var stringToHash = "10123456789" + "2014:11:25-15:42:00" + "20.00" + "826" + "sharedsecret";

Console.WriteLine(stringToHash);
// outputs:
// 101234567892014:11:25-15:42:0020.00826sharedsecret

var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToHash);

var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(hexString);
// outputs:
// 3130313233343536373839323031343A31313A32352D31353A34323A303032302E3030383236736861726564736563726574

SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
var password = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
var result = BitConverter.ToString(password).ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(result);
// outputs:
// c8069048623d6b98a08454e43e1a02a42cf7d61d

var hexStringBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexString);
var hexStringPassword = sha.ComputeHash(hexStringBytes);
var hexStringResult = BitConverter.ToString(hexStringPassword).ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine(hexStringResult);
// outputs:
// bd857ca08446001f7182fbbbd41e747abe302a87
```

The first two outputs are the same. The original strings are identical, as are the ASCII hex arrays after conversion, but sha1() in PHP is giving me a different outcome to .net's SHA1CryptoServiceProvider. If I convert that output to a string and hash it again, the result is also different.

In .net, an object has to be in the form of a byte array before you can create an SHA hash from it, and I don't understand what I need to convert to the byte array to produce the same output as the PHP code.

This is problematic as the third party service I am posting to uses the PHP version to verify an object on their end, and my program is written in .net. I could write a middle-man in PHP and relay through that, but I really don't want have to do that.

Any insight into why the two are giving different results? Thanks

Comment: You forgot to actually use `hexString` in your C# program. I don't understand why you want to go to hex string before hashing anyway, but the fact that you miss out that step in .net is the problem.

Comment: `hexstring` is just a string representation of the byte array in hex surely? I'm using the byte array, I just converted it to a string to print it to the console and see if it matched the PHP equivalent at that stage. Are you saying I should take that string, convert that back to a byte array and hash it to achieve the same result as PHP? As for why, this is sample code provided by a third party showing how they calculate their hash, I am trying to replicate it in C#.

Comment: You are converting 2 different values. PHP converts hex, .net does not.

Comment: What's the difference though? I thought they were just two ways to represent the same data (base8/base16)? So hashing the byte array in C# was equivalent to hashing the hex array in php?

Comment: Programmatically the values would be equivalent. But not in the scheme of hashing something. Hashing an ascii value of "cat" would not be the same as hashing the binary equivalent.

Comment: Ok. In .net something needs to be in the form of a byte array though before you can hash it. If I take `hexString` and hash it I still get a different result than in PHP. Is there no way to replicate the code in .net?

Comment: There are a lot of issues...check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607272/why-is-my-sha1-hash-not-matching

Comment: The OP here seems to have the opposite problem. She wants to change her PHP code to match the hashing result of .net code. The PHP code I have the same code used by a third party, so I need to change my .net code to product the same output as their PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it.  Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336017/same-string-different-sha1-hash-values-obtained-from-vb-net-and-php) and a question I ran across 2 days ago and can't find.

```
public string HashItThePHPWay(string hashMe)
        {
            var sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            string b64 = ByteArrayToString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hashMe));
            var b64Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64);
            var result = sha.ComputeHash(b64Bytes);
            return BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }

    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
        {
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        }
        return hex.ToString().ToLower();
    }
```

Comment: The real trick is removing the dashes from the b64 string before getting the ASCII encoding

Comment: Thanks very much, this had me stumped

Comment: May I know why you use both `BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLower()` and `ByteArrayToString(..)` function in 2 different places since they are giving the same result?